# Django Dynamic model register in admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I'm using django 1.11 and I tried to to create django dynamic models by referring this link https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels , by executing each and every step it runs without any issue, but How can I see this created table in django admin panel?

***action.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label='', module='', options=None, admin_opts=None):
    """
    Create specified model
    """
    class Meta:
        # Using type('Meta', ...) gives a dictproxy error during model creation
        pass

    if app_label:
        # app_label must be set using the Meta inner class
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)

    # Update Meta with any options that were provided
    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}

    # Add in any fields that were provided
    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)

    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    # Create an Admin class if admin options were provided
    if admin_opts is not None:
        print admin_opts
        class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            pass
        for key, value in admin_opts:
            setattr(Admin, key, value)
        admin.site.register(model, Admin)

    return model
```

***In Console***:

```
from action import create_model
from django.db import models

fields = {
    'first_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
    'last_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
    '__str__': lambda self: '%s %s' (self.first_name, self.last_name),
}

options = {
    'ordering': ['last_name', 'first_name'],
    'verbose_name': 'valued customer',
}

admin_opts = {}

model = create_model('Person', fields,
    options=options,
    admin_opts=admin_opts,
    app_label='form',
    module='project.app.model',
)
```

I can see no. of fields by

```
len(model._meta.fields)
```

But I have no idea of, how to register the created model in admin, and what parameter will come inside `admin_opts = {}` , how can i do **makemigrations** and **migrate**,how can I access this model in ***views.py***, from where i will import this model .Can you guys please help me for this , it will be very useful for me and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to execute this function.

```
def install(model):
from django.core.management import sql, color
from django.db import connection

# Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations,
# so dynamic models need to bypass django.core.management.syncdb.
# On the plus side, this allows individual models to be installed
# without installing the entire project structure.
# On the other hand, this means that things like relationships and
# indexes will have to be handled manually.
# This installs only the basic table definition.

# disable terminal colors in the sql statements
style = color.no_style()

cursor = connection.cursor()
statements, pending = sql.sql_model_create(model, style)
for sql in statements:
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, but i'm using the latest django version 1.11, in this the `sql.sql_model_create` is not found, how can I achieve this in 1.11?

Comment: Any How  I created the table, but how can I register it in admin? I to tired many method but I cannot achieve this. can you guys please help me out for this.it will be very great full for me. Thanks in advacne

Comment: Have you tried this "admin.site.register(model_name)" after having a dynamic model instance in views.py?

Comment: Can you please elaborate me, how can I achieve this in the views.py, so far I'm trying this in the console only.

Comment: Can you please help me out, how can I call these table as html forms

Answer (score 3):

```
with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(Model)
```

This is from github source code , try it instead of sql_model_create and I try to success in my project,and it's true..

I have worked hard for a long time because I don't find django-dynamic-model in "django 1.10".